# Prepend all CSS selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex, css-selectors

Is there a text filter or javascript/jquery function that will prepend all css selectors in a stylesheet with a something? I am trying to affect just one div with twitter bootstrap but it is affecting the sidebar outside of it, is there anyway to do this? (I do not want to use an iframe.)

EDIT:

All I want, is to be able to prepend an ID "#content" to every selector in a css file.

Comment: Hmmmm... why don't you find a way to uniquely identify the div instead? Changing all of the style of the page seems like a bad idea, because it could break other things

Comment: Can't agree with @nico enough. Post your site or a fiddle, there's got to be a better way

Comment: It wont break the page, I want to apply the twitter bootstrap css to a single div, i want to prepend only the css in the bootstrap.css file.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your comment under sabithpocker's answer tells me that instead of dynamically changing your styles, you are looking to statically modify your CSS. I think this would be easiest with a regular expression:

Find: `([,|\}][\s$]*)([\.#]?-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)`
Replace with: `$1#content $2`

**Breakdown of Regex**

- `([,|\}][\s$]*)` - Finds the `}` or `,` from the previous style followed by whitespace (spaces/tabs: `\s`, newlines: `$`). The closing brace\comma keeps the regex from looking inside the body of your style.
- `[\.#]?` - Matches the starting `#` or `.` in the style name, if it is present.
- `-?[_a-zA-Z]+` - CSS style names can start with an underscore or letters. Also, style names can be prepended by a dash.
- `[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*` - Matches the rest of the style name. This can be omitted, but it might be nice to know the style name of all the styles that were modified.
- `$1#content $2` - The `}` (or `,`) and whitespace is left the way it was found (`$1`). It is followed by your inserted text `#content` (note the space), which is then followed by the style name (`$2`).

I tested this in Notepad++ and it works on my stylesheets.

It should be noted, that if your CSS is not compressed (and is multiline),
you will need editor that supports multi-line regular expressions (Notepad++ does).

Comment: THANK YOU!! It got most of them but it left some like this: `#content audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
}` It didn't get canvas or video.

Comment: @Raymond - Ah, yeah, that would require a bit more. I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: @Raymond - Updated to include comma-separated names. (`\}` just needs to change to `[,|\}]`)

Comment: @Rusty good explanation of the reg exp. Raymond please add regex tag to the question

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't get everything (example: put an `a` tag in a media query)

Comment: Regarding my comment above, you can do an additional `css = css.replace(/(@media[^{]+{[\s$]*)([\.#]?-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/, "$1" + prependClass + " $2");` to catch these situations.

Comment: You just saved me a TON of time. The only issue I noticed was that my `@font-face` rule was also getting the content and it was causing fonts not to load from a URL, but that was an easy manual fix. If anyone else uses this technique with Bootstrap and notices that Glyphicons aren't appearing, take a look at the `@font-face` rule.

Comment: Watch out for base64 encoded data; it will sometimes get picked up by the regex.

Comment: @austin what do you mean by take a look at the font-face rule? How do i fix it?

Comment: Almost there, it misses anything that has a comment `/* foo */` infront of the selector or the global *, consider https://gist.github.com/er1c/7685e4a79c265f58e11a6428896c2c90 - only the last  `.FloatRight` will get it applied

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this answer. However, I have a case where the JS regex only replaces only the first match. From Chrome console, try `"  .{}  .table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td, .table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th { background: blue; } .table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > td, .table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > th { background: yellow; }".replace(/([,|\}][\s$]*)([\.#]?-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/,  "$1" + "#myDiv" + " $2");` and you will see you get only the first part replaced. Same code does work on http://regexr.com/. Any idea?

Comment: @MarianoMartinezPeck - You need to use global matching by putting a 'g' after the last forward slash: `/regex/g`

Comment: Hi guys, same as @ericpeters here...I need the support for `/* foo */.` too. Any idea how to improve the regex with that?

Comment: @MarianoMartinezPeck I think I figured this out...but I had to do two different regex's due to an issue with java not supporting PCRE....but you can see my code at: https://gist.github.com/er1c/2546306666425fab1be9b37c92c8270b

Comment: Hi. I am having troubles with colors as hex that start with letters (if they start with numbers they are correct). The css in question is something like: `background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ae9e9e, #454545);`. In addition to colors starting with letters it doesn't work either if I use rgb. In all cases, the result is something like: `background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #myDiv #ae9e9e, #454545)`. Any ideas?

Comment: This is amazing! But one thing I noticed is that it does capture rules declared directly after `/* */` comments, as well as the first rule inside `@` queries.

Answer (score 8):

Improved upon RustyTheBoyRobot and BoltClock♦ answer to allow for comments and media queries.

Find: `([,|\}][\s$]*)((?|\/\/.*[\s$]+|.*\/\*.*\*\/[\s$]*|@media.*\{[\s$]*|)*)([\.#]?-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)`

Replace with: `$1$2 #content $3`

## Edit

It's been brought to my attention that the code I supplied only works for PHP.

Here is an improved version that should work in Javascript and PHP

**Regex Pattern***

```
(^(?:\s|[^@{])*?|[},]\s*)(\/\/.*\s+|.*\/\*[^*]*\*\/\s*|@media.*{\s*|@font-face.*{\s*)*([.#]?-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(?=[^}]*{)
```

**Full Example***

```
var outputString = inputString.replace(
    /(^(?:\s|[^@{])*?|[},]\s*)(\/\/.*\s+|.*\/\*[^*]*\*\/\s*|@media.*{\s*|@font-face.*{\s*)*([.#]?-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(?=[^}]*{)/g,
    "$1$2 #content $3"
);
```

This should also fix @Mariano Martinez Peck issue with `background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ae9e9e, #454545);` and the issue with `@font-face`

Comment: I get an error compiling that is it suppose to be `?|` or `?:`?

Comment: Eh, so the `?|` is a PCRE thing, so not supported in java

Comment: I am getting an error when trying to use this from JS. I am trying this: `" .{} /*.table tbody > tr > td {font-family: verdana; font-size: small} */ .researchCompanyReportTableControls { display: none; } ".replace(/([,|\}][\s$]*)((?|\/\/.*[\s$]+|.*\/\*.*\*\/[\s$]*|@media.*\{[\s$]*|)*)([\.#]?-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/g, "$1" + "$2" + "#myDiv" + " $3");
` but it fails with a invalid group. Any ideas? I looks like the it doesn't like the `?|`.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done easier with the use of SCSS. Simply take your existing CSS, nest it all with a #my-new-selector { ... } and then run it through a SCSS to CSS compiler (there are online tools that can do this without you having to install anything.

Comment: In the present day, this is a much more consistent and honestly easier approach. Regex is very fiddly between systems, and you'll come across lots of edge cases, but SCSS parses and understands the css, so unless the SCSS compiler is bad, you will most likely get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround (if you really need this done this way):

1. Wait till window loads and all styles are applied
2. Grab the elements you want the applied styles intact
3. Get their styles and apply it inline

For a cross browser implementation you can use the jquery plugin shown below:

```
$('#mydiv *').each(function(){
    $(this).css($(this).getStyleObject());
    });
```

Then disable the original style sheet

```
document.stylesheets[n].disabled = true;
//or use this : $('link[title=mystyle]')[0].disabled=true;

//n should be index of style sheet -- counts external + internal style sheets
```

Plugin:

```
/*
 * getStyleObject Plugin for jQuery JavaScript Library
 * From: http://upshots.org/?p=112
 */

(function($){
    $.fn.getStyleObject = function(){
        var dom = this.get(0);
        var style;
        var returns = {};
        if(window.getComputedStyle){
            var camelize = function(a,b){
                return b.toUpperCase();
            };
            style = window.getComputedStyle(dom, null);
            for(var i = 0, l = style.length; i < l; i++){
                var prop = style[i];
                var camel = prop.replace(/\-([a-z])/g, camelize);
                var val = style.getPropertyValue(prop);
                returns[camel] = val;
            };
            return returns;
        };
        if(style = dom.currentStyle){
            for(var prop in style){
                returns[prop] = style[prop];
            };
            return returns;
        };
        return this.css();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to export it so that I can just save the .css file? I would rather this be a static file.

Comment: Whay do you need that, can you explain what you are exactly trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to apply the twitter bootstrap css (bootstrap.css) to a single div, currently it is affecting everything on the page.

Answer (score 0):

No the stylesheet is just a copy paste file. you have to wrap all you want with a unique identifier and then refer to this using this unique identifier.

Comment: I have a unique identifier, the issue is that all of the css does not match that, i need a way to process the text and prepend `#content ` to each selector.

Comment: The css comes as text, then in browser its kept as objects in document.stylesheets array , modern browsers has ways of attacking them directly . have a look at quirks for compatibility and available functions http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html

Comment: @sabithpocker I know how CSS works, I want a text filter for a text file specific to CSS formatting, using that filter I want to add a prefix to all selectors in that text file.