# How to scope CSS in chrome extension content scripts

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension that injects a button onto a page. When this button is clicked, it launches a twitter bootstrap modal. However, the css that is injected with the twitter bootstrap is affecting the pages themselves and I only want them to affect the modal divs. How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one true way to do that and it involves LESS

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14145510/1060487

Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15115171/1060487

Both approaches should work fine.

I've experimented with 1 other solution:

http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/

Which DOES NOT work in Chrome but there is a [polyfill here](https://github.com/PM5544/scoped-polyfill), which doesn't really seem to work that well...

Check the support here: http://caniuse.com/style-scoped

**Summary**: the LESS route seems to be the best solution right now...

Answer (score 1):

I recently created Boundary, a CSS+JS library to solve problems just like this. Boundary creates elements that are completely separate from the existing webpage's CSS.

Take creating a dialog for example. After installing Boundary, you can do this in your content script

```js
var dialog = Boundary.createBox("yourDialogID", "yourDialogClassName");

Boundary.loadBoxCSS("#yourDialogID", "style-for-elems-in-dialog.css");

Boundary.appendToBox(
    "#yourDialogID",
    "<button id='submit_button'>submit</button>"
);

Boundary.find("#submit_button").click(function() {
  // find() function returns a regular jQuery DOM element
  // so you can do whatever you want with it.
  // some js after button is clicked.
});
```

Elements within #yourDialogID will not be affected by the existing webpage.

Hope this helps. Please let me know if you have any question.

https://github.com/liviavinci/Boundary

Comment: I tried to use Boundary as I want to open a twitter bootstrap modal from within a chrome extension contentscript.
The modal is shown but not as a modal as I and probably you are used to it (over the current web page) but just as part of the webpage where the iframe was added. 
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @TorstenFeld can you please be more specific? Maybe some code example and screenshots? Feel free to email me liviavinci@gmail.com