# Integrate CSS framework work only in specified class or ID

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, zurb-foundation

I have website built from scratch and my specified system build on Bootstrap or foundation. When I try to integrate it on my website, all my website start using Bootstrap or foundation style.

Is possible to make work this CSS only in for example

```
<div id="bootstrap_only">
    <table class="table table-bordered">...</table> <!-- here works -->
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered">...</table> <!-- here don't work -->
```

Comment: That's pretty much how they're supposed to work. Typically you would either set your defaults and compile bootstrap or foundation with your new settings, or you would write css to override their styles.

Comment: One of idea was rewrite all boostrap css file like 

#boostrap_only table {...}

but it will be painfull :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is many ways .

1- using less ( in your less file include your bootstrap like this )

```
.bootstrap {
    @import "/path-to-bootstrap-less.less"
    @import "/path-to-bootstrap-responsive-less.less"
}
```

2- detailed solution :

The final fix was to use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com) (recommended by someone off-site), as that allows you to nest elements and then automatically produce the final CSS. Step by step the process is:

1. Concatenate the two Bootstrap files (`bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap-responsive.css`) into `bootstrap-all.css`.
2. Create a new SASS file, `bootstrap-all.scss`, with the content `div.bootstrap {`.
3. Append `bootstrap-all.css` to `bootstrap-all.scss`.
4. Close the `div.bootstrap` selector by appending `}` to `bootstrap-all.scss`.
5. Run SASS on `bootstrap-all.scss` to produce a final CSS file.
6. Run [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) on the final file to produce a minimised version.
7. Add minimised version to head element and wrap everything I want the styles to apply to in `<div class="bootstrap"></div>`.

for reference see this links [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831346/applying-css-styles-only-to-certain-elements)

Comment: i didn't try yet but i think that's is the solution of this situation