# What dependencies does Bootstrap require for it to work properly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

What dependencies does Bootstrap require for it to work properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying CSS styles only to certain elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831346/applying-css-styles-only-to-certain-elements)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Bootstrap is a CSS framework which helps you with providing certain styles out-of-the-box for the whole website. Which styles exactly do you want for one simple paragraph? You could imitate Bootstrap for it, instead of importing the whole framework just for it.

Comment: @ParthPatel no it is not duplicate of that.. Check now i edit it more concisely

Comment: @ParthPatel remove your duplication

Comment: @RebeccaJoanna Bootstrap has nothing to do with AJAX and PHP. Twitter Bootstrap is a CSS/JS framework which helps you with common frontend stuff. It doesn't mess with AJAX calls, and definitely not with a back-end technology such as PHP.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović can we link it with php files

Comment: Take a look at [Getting started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) page from official Twitter Bootstrap site to see how to import Bootstrap into your project. PHP has nothing to do with it.

Comment: okay Thanks.. Is my question is relevant or bad question?

Comment: @RebeccaJoanna you just need to add references of bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js. Explore the official documentation of bootstrap it will help you to get started

Comment: okay Thanks @ParthPatel remove ur duplication from my question

Comment: You always can see the dependencies in his official repo, check the bootstrap repo on github, and probably you'll see a main javascript file and a css main file ( minified or not )  thats your question, but what you should do as @ParthPatel said is check the official doc, a getting started guide.

Comment: @HéctorLeón ok thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add below CDN links in your html :

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you dear yeah i have seen that on official site